# Django cannot find static file on proxy pass

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

I have managed to make my Django app work from a VPS location, but now it does not load one of the static files which is requested by the app template.

The application path is 'http://dev.apps.net/tacdb/'

static files config in settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "mysite/static")

# Site name.
SITE_NAME = basename(DJANGO_ROOT)

# Absolute filesystem path to the top-level project folder.
SITE_ROOT = dirname(DJANGO_ROOT)

STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "mysite", "/static"),)
```

The javascript request in the html file:

```
{% block javascript %}
<script src="{% static '/js/books.js' %}"></script>

{% endblock %}
```

the html file is located */tacdb/mysite/tacdashboard/templates/items/item_list.html*

the request for the static file is 
**http://dev.apps.net/static/js/books.js**

I use a proxy pass to in Apache for this app. If I run the app directly on the port using runserver, everything works fine.

Any ideeas what is going wrong?

P.S. this problem appeared when i added location to the proxypass.

Thanks a lot!

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName dev.apps.net

   ProxyRequests Off
   ProxyPreserveHost On
   ProxyVia Full
   <Proxy *>
     Require all granted
   </Proxy>

   <Location /nodejs>
      ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8090
      ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8090
   </Location>

   <Location /tacdb>
    ProxyPass http://0.0.0.0:8080/tacdb
    ProxyPassReverse http://0.0.0.0:8080/tacdb
   </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Can you share your configuration file for the proxy pass?

Comment: sure. i have added it to the main question.

Comment: it is only this file which cannot be found (books.js). Other work?! :|

Comment: Shouldn't that be `<script src="{% static 'name-of-app/js/books.js' %}"></script>`? Could you share how you are referencing all the other js that's working?

Comment: this is in base.html ```<script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>```

Comment: i have tried this as well (<script src="{% static 'name-of-app/js/books.js' %}"></script>) but still not working. i don't understand why did it work with no location in Apache...

Comment: actuallly, I just discovered that none of the JS static files are loaded. only the css...

Comment: I was wondering why the bootstrap would work and the books.js wouldn't!

Comment: I am wondering the same thing. It is only sincr i added the server location. If i run it as runserver, on port 8000 it works. :| It worked from the vs ps proxy pass but on root. Thanks for the support!

Comment: actually, after I deleted the browser cache, the bootstrap stopped working. I thinkg the issue is that the url for the static files is missing the server location: http://dev.apps.gdceur..net/static/js/bootstrap.min.js
it should have the server location before static :-?

Answer (score 0):

i changed the config in settings.py and it now works! :)

```
STATIC_URL = "/tacdb/static"

STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "mysite", "tacdb/static"))
```